# Roomba Connector

Tags: robotics, connector, roomba

I am getting started with robotics and would like to start with some roomba programming. I come from a programmer background so I thought that would be a good starting point and since I already owned a roomba it was a natural choice.

I looked into the how to get it connected to my computer and there are various options out there but I am not sure which is best. Here are my conditions:

- I don't want to make anything. Not that advanced yet.
- It needs to be reliably run on a Mac and linux machine.
- It can be bluetooth but doesn't have to be. I'm planning on mounting my netbook to the top of the roomba.

I'd appreciate help in knowing which way to go.

Edit: A bit more info that is relevant. I am planning on programming it using Pyro, so any solution needs to support pyro (which is why my mounted netbook idea came into being). Also, I own an Arduino and a Teensy although I wasn't planning to use them for this project. Just mentioning them in case they can be useful.

Answer (score 1):

I've added to my roomba 530 a RouterBoard RB411 with a WiFi MiniPCI card and connected the routerboard serial port to the roomba connector using a level adapter (there are many schematics on "hacking roomba" sites, using just diodes and resistors. I've used the common MAX232).
Routerboard can be powered by unregulated roomba battery voltage thru the connector, and with a driver RFC2217 compliant you can send command to a virtual com port on the local machine. Commands are relayed to the routerboard serial port and to the robot, and the robot answers are relayer to the virtual com port on the local machine. 
The RB411 wired ethernet port can be used to relay an onboard IP camera.